# A question about a probability inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, convergence-divergence

If we have two conditions
$$M_n(\hat\theta_n)+o_p(1)\ge M_n(\theta_0)$$
and
$$M_n(\theta_0)\overset{P}\to M(\theta_0).$$

Can we obtain the result below directly
$$M_n(\hat\theta_n)+o_p(1)\ge M(\theta_0)?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\th{\theta}$
$\def\ze{\zeta}$

The first condition means that there exist random variable $\xi_n$ with $\xi_n\to0$ in probability such that
$$
M_n(\hat\th_0) + \xi_n \ge M_n(\th_0).
$$
Let $\ze_n=M_n(\th_0)-M(\th_0)$. Then $\ze_n\to0$ in probability and
$$
M_n(\hat\th_0) + \xi_n - \ze_n \ge M(\th_0).
$$
Since $\xi_n-\ze_n\to0$ in probability, this means
$$
M_n(\hat\th_0) + o_p(1) \ge M(\th_0).
$$